# when left swipe a tableview cell to the left edge of the phone, it will auto trigger the delete UITableViewRowAction , how to disable this?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

when left swipe a tableview cell to the left  edge of the phone, it will auto trigger the delete UITableViewRowAction , how to disable this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

on ios11 ,the swipe action is defined in the delegate method :

```
-(UISwipeActionsConfiguration *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(11_0){
    UIContextualAction *deleteAction = [UIContextualAction contextualActionWithStyle:UIContextualActionStyleNormal title:@"哈喽" handler:^(UIContextualAction * _Nonnull action, __kindof UIView * _Nonnull sourceView, void (^ _Nonnull completionHandler)(BOOL)) {
        NSLog(@"hello");
        completionHandler(YES);
    }];
    UISwipeActionsConfiguration *config = [UISwipeActionsConfiguration configurationWithActions:@[deleteAction]];
    config.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = NO;//this line will disable auto trigger the action when perform full swipe
        return config;
}
```

if this delegate method is not impelemented,it will use the

```
-(NSArray<UITableViewRowAction *> *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

the auto trigger action is determined by the **UISwipeActionsConfiguration's performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe**, so just set this value to false